# How to print Extended ASCII characters correctly with json.dumps() - Python

Tags: python, json, extended-ascii

I have this JSON file with some characters that belongs to `Extended ASCII characters`, for example `», •, ñ, Ó, Ä`

```
{
    "@index": "1",
    "row": [
    {
        "col": [
        {
            "text": {
            "@x": "1",
            "#text": "Text » 1 A\\CÓ"
            }
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "col": [
        {
            "text": {
            "@x": "7",
            "#text": "Text • 2 Wñ"
            }
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

I load it in `d` variable with `json.load()` as below

```
import json 

with open('in.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
```

and `d` looks like this:

```
d = {'@index': '1', 'row': [{'col': [{'text': {'@x': '1', '#text': 'Text » 1 A\\CÓ'}}]}, {'col': [{'text': {'@x': '7', '#text': 'Text • 2 Wñ'}}]}]}
```

Then applying the following code, the json stored in `d` is converted to one level nested json (Until here, the extended ASCII characters are fine)

```
>>> z = {**d, 'row':[c['text'] for b in d['row'] for c in b['col']]}
>>> z
{'@index': '1', 'row': [{'@x': '1', '#text': 'Text » 1 A\\CÓ'}, {'@x': '7', '#text': 'Text • 2 Wñ'}]}
>>>
```

The issue comes when I use `json.dumps()` because the extended ASCII characters are printed wrong as you can see below.

How to fix this? Thanks for any help.

```
>>> print(json.dumps(z, indent=4))
{
    "@index": "1",
    "row": [
        {
            "@x": "1",
            "#text": "Text \u00bb 1 A\\C\u00d3"
        },
        {
            "@x": "7",
            "#text": "Text \u2022 2 W\u00f1"
        }
    ]
}
>>>
```

Comment: The characters are not printed "wrong"; `\uXXXX` escapes are a perfectly valid alternative way to represent characters.

Comment: But I need they be human readable. I hope make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`ensure_ascii`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) parameter.

```
import json                   

raw_data = '{"data": ["»", "•", "ñ", "Ó", "Ä"]}'
json_data = json.loads(raw_data)

print(json_data)
# {u'data': [u'\xbb', u'\u2022', u'\xf1', u'\xd3', u'\xc4']}

processed_data = json.dumps(json_data, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False, encoding='utf-8')

print(processed_data)
# {
#     "data": [
#         "»", 
#         "•", 
#         "ñ", 
#         "Ó", 
#         "Ä"
#     ]
# }
```

For Python2 you'd do:

```
processed_data = json.dumps(json_data, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Your sample code works for me in python2, and this line `json.dumps(json_data, ...ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')`  works for me in Python3. But when I test in Python3 the `print(processed_data)` looks like this `b'{\n    "data": [\n        "\xc2\xbb",\n ..` not like the pretty print in your example.